# Was Hashirama in Sage Mode while he summoned the huge wooden buddha with few thousand hands?

Tags: naruto

In Chapter 621 Hashirama summoned a Buddha statue. While doing that, he has some markings on his face similar to the ones Naruto has when in Sage Mode. Does Hashirama have some sort of Sage Mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is Sage Mode, since Senpou means Sage Art. The technique is Senpou Mokuton: Shinsuusenju ([Sage Art Wood Release: True Several Thousand Hands](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Art:_Wood_Release:_True_Several_Thousand_Hands)).

[image: Senpou Mokuton]
[image: Shinsuusenju]